# how to call a method of a main_activity from a normal class in android

Tags: java, android, class, android-activity

Hi i use this post [Background process timer on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578586/background-process-timer-on-android) for the timeer in background process

my timer code in main activity is

```
int repeatTime = 5;
    AlarmManager processTimer = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, processTimerReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    processTimer.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),repeatTime*1000, pendingIntent);
```

and my code in class processTimerReceiver is:

```
public class processTimerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
    m.get_start_info();

}

}
```

i want to call method get_start_info() in main activity but app crashed

full my main activity is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    int repeatTime = 5;
    AlarmManager processTimer = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, processTimerReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    processTimer.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),repeatTime*1000, pendingIntent);

    get_start_info();

}

public void get_start_info() {
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest("www.example.com",
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                       // any

                        sendNotification();

                        //any
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

public void sendNotification() {


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, azegar_mail_list.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


    //mp.start();
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    builder.setContentTitle("آزگار");
    builder.setContentText("نامه جدید برای شما ارسال شده است");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setSound(soundUri);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Will display the notification in the notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

}
```

my error is :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.azegar.www.azegar.processTimerReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2539)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:167)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
                  at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:551)
                  at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:327)
                  at com.azegar.www.azegar.MainActivity.get_start_info(MainActivity.java:438)
                  at com.azegar.www.azegar.processTimerReceiver.onReceive(processTimerReceiver.java:12)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2532)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:167) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5341) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:929) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are calling `get_start_info()` outside of the MainActivity, then move `get_start_info()` and `sendNotification` out of MainActivity.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because you are trying to use `MainActivity`'s context to build a notification inside `sendNotification` and that context is null because you are instantiating `MainActivity` with the `new` keyword (You should not instantiate a new activity with the new keyword). Instead, pass the `BroadcastReceiver`'s context as a parameter to `sendNotification` and use it to build the notification.

Parts of the code which uses `Context`:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, azegar_mail_list.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Here, instead of using `this`, you should use the `Context` passed as a parameter.

Comment: Hi merterpam your code is very good this code work for me thanks

Comment: Hi ebrehim, thank you and welcome to Stackoverflow =). If you are satisfied with the answer and want to close the question, please mark the answer as accepted.